# Beam DirectRunner Calcite can't specify name

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-internals

I'm running a simplified version of this [beam tutorial](https://youtu.be/zx4p-UNSmrA?t=246), but running it using the DirectRunner on my local machine.

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms.sql import SqlTransform
import os

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    rows = (p |
            beam.Create([
                beam.Row(col1="val1", col2="col2_val1"),
                beam.Row(col1="val2", col2="col2_val2"),
            ]
            ))
    ({"my_table": rows} | SqlTransform("""SELECT * FROM my_table"""))
```

If I change `my_table` to `PCOLLECTION` it works (although for it to really work I need to just pass in `rows` instead of the dict.

The error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lib/scratch/test_join.py", line 12, in <module>
    ({"my_table": rows} | SqlTransform("""SELECT * FROM my_table"""))
  File "/Users/steeling/src/versions/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 606, in __ror__
    result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)
  File "/Users/steeling/src/versions/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 694, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
  File "/Users/steeling/src/versions/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 185, in apply
    return m(transform, input, options)
  File "/Users/steeling/src/versions/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 215, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/Users/steeling/src/versions/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 305, in expand
    raise RuntimeError(response.error)
RuntimeError: org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.ParseException: Unable to parse query SELECT * FROM my_table
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.CalciteQueryPlanner.convertToBeamRel(CalciteQueryPlanner.java:214)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.BeamSqlEnv.parseQuery(BeamSqlEnv.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:171)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:109)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:548)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$TransformProvider.apply(ExpansionService.java:367)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:470)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:546)
    at org.apache.beam.model.expansion.v1.ExpansionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ExpansionServiceGrpc.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p36p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.tools.ValidationException: org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 22: Object 'my_table' not found
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.prepare.PlannerImpl.validate(PlannerImpl.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.CalciteQueryPlanner.convertToBeamRel(CalciteQueryPlanner.java:183)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 22: Object 'my_table' not found
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:463)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:824)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:809)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.newValidationError(SqlValidatorImpl.java:4805)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.resolveImpl(IdentifierNamespace.java:172)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.validateImpl(IdentifierNamespace.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate(AbstractNamespace.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace(SqlValidatorImpl.java:995)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3109)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3091)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateSelect(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3363)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SelectNamespace.validateImpl(SelectNamespace.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate(AbstractNamespace.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace(SqlValidatorImpl.java:995)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect.validate(SqlSelect.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateScopedExpression(SqlValidatorImpl.java:930)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validate(SqlValidatorImpl.java:637)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.prepare.PlannerImpl.validate(PlannerImpl.java:215)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Object 'my_table' not found
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:463)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex(Resources.java:572)
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encounter this error since you only have one PCollection. It seems that Apache Beam will use `PCOLLECTION` as table source even if you created a dictionary that has a key value pair of `{"my_table": rows}`.

As a workaround, if you would like to explicitly define a table name in your SQL statement you can create a temporary PCollection that contains dummy values. Create a dictionary that have a key value pair of the two PCollections.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms.sql import SqlTransform
import os

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    rows = (p |
            "create rows" >> beam.Create([
                beam.Row(col1="val1", col2="col2_val1"),
                beam.Row(col1="val2", col2="col2_val2"),
            ]
            ))
    rows_2 = (p |
            "create rows_2" >> beam.Create([
                beam.Row(col1_1="val1", col2_1="123"),
            ]
            ))

    ({"my_table": rows, "my_table2": rows_2} | SqlTransform("""SELECT * FROM my_table""")
            | beam.Map(lambda row: "col1: %s, col2: %s" % (row.col1,row.col2))
            | beam.Map(print))
```

The output is:

[image]

You can open a [Apache Beam JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM) to request if your use case could be done on the future releases.